# CloudKit data not updating in second device only in simulator and first device

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I'm trying to keep the data from `CloudKit` in sync in multiple devices. With the following code, I can successfully add, load and get a notification when a record has been modified in `CloudKit`, my issue is that this only works when I use the simulator to modify the data and a physical device to see the notifications.

Here is how I'm using it.

1. I installed the app in the simulator and in an iPhone.
2. From the simulator, I go and enter a new note/record and I get the notification in the iPhone, which is what I want. I can also enter records directly from the `CloudKit dashboard` and I also get the notifications in the iPhone.
3. The third step and what doesn't work is... I went to my wife's iPhone, installed the app from Xcode and signed in to `iTunes & App Store` with the same account I used in the simulator and in the first device where the data updates, then I went and entered data in the simulator and on the first iPhone but I don't get any notification in my wife's iPhone. I tried entering data directly in my wife's iPhone and it seems to persist the data since I can quit the app and the data doesn't get lost. So, I end up with totally different data in both phones, in my wife's iPhone I only see what was entered directly in that phone and in my first phone, I see what was entered directly there, in the simulator or in the CloudKit dashboard.

I'm probably misunderstanding the whole ecosystem and how it works. What I was expecting is that every phone that has the app installed and it's logged-in with the same `iTunes & App Store` login credentials would see the updates in all devices.

What part am I misunderstanding here?

Here is the Code:

### Main ViewController

**Adding Records**

```
public func saveNotestoCloud(){
    let privateDatabase = CKContainer.default().database(with: .private)
    if let title =  self.textfield.text, let body = textView.text, let record = self.note?.record{
        record["title"] = title
        record["note"] = body
        self.note?.record = record

        privateDatabase.save(record) { (record,error) in
            if let error = error{
                print("Error  \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            print("Successfully saved record \(record?.recordID.recordName ?? "")")
        }
    }
}
```

### App Delegate

**Registering the notifications**

```
let privateDatabase = CKContainer.default().database(with: .private)

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.createSubscriptions()

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]){ (granter, error) in
        guard error == nil else{
            print(error!)
            return
        }
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return true
}

private func createSubscriptions(){

    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Notes",
                                                       predicate: predicate,
                                                       subscriptionID: "SubscriptionID",
                                                       options: [CKQuerySubscription.Options.firesOnRecordCreation,  CKQuerySubscription.Options.firesOnRecordDeletion, CKQuerySubscription.Options.firesOnRecordUpdate])

    let notificationInfo = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
    notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = "New Note"
    notificationInfo.shouldBadge = true
    subscription.notificationInfo =  notificationInfo
    let privateData = CKContainer.default().database(with: .private)
    privateData.save(subscription){ result, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, CloudKit relies on the account that is signed in under iCloud in the device settings, ***not*** the iTunes & App Store account.

If you want your wife's iPhone to see the same CloudKit data, you will have to sign out, and sign back in with your Apple ID in the iCloud Settings.

Comment: Hmm, make sense, but does that means that her stuff will be uploaded to mu iCloud account, right?

Comment: It would mean all her stuff is merged with your iCloud account, yes (which you probably don't want). If you want an easier way to share data on CloudKit across multiple devices and multiple iCloud accounts, just save the data to the **public** database in the same CloudKit container.

Comment: How does that work, if I save the data in the public database, does that mean that every user will see that same data? Let's pretend for a moment that this a shopping list where each user will have his/her own lists and some users will want to share their lists with some other family members, how would this work by having the lists stored in the public database?

Comment: You'd want a `ShoppingList` record type and a `People` record type. On the `People` record type, you'd have a `Reference List` field that contains a list of the `ShoppingList`s that the people have access to. So when you query a person, you'd get a list of what they have access to.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Have you used the Shared database? I'm wondering if this is more appropriate, maybe have the records stored in the private database and then the user would share only the items he/she wants with other users.

Comment: Yes, `CKShare` is another great option. It can be a little cumbersome to get running, but this sort of thing is exactly what it’s for.

Comment: Thank you for your help!